# How to get the files in numeric order from the specified directory in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sorting

I have to retrieve list of file names from the specific directory using numeric order.Actually file names are combination of strings and numeric values but end with numeric values.

For example : page_1.png,page_2.png,page3.png...,page10.png,page_11.png,page_12.png...

my c# code is below :

```
string filePath="D:\\vs-2010projects\\delete_sample\\delete_sample\\myimages\\";
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.png");
```

It retrieved in the following format:

```
page_1.png
page_10.png
page_11.png
page_12.png
page_2.png...
```

I am expecting to retrieve the list ordered like this:

```
page_1.png
page_2.png
page_3.png
[...]
page_10.png
page_11.png
page_12.png
```

Comment: This is normal behavior... You would need to name your files "page_01.png" and so on...

Comment: Fill them in object.Then do some string mainupulation to get string between _ and . and change it into int and assign some property of the object.
Then fetch item according to that property after ordering the list.It's very simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following code, which sort your file names based on the numeric values. Keep in mind, this logic works based on some conventions such as the availability of '_'. You are free to modify the code to add more defensive approach save you from any business case.

```
var vv = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Image").GetFileSystemInfos("*.bmp").OrderBy(fs=>int.Parse(fs.Name.Split('_')[1].Substring(0, fs.Name.Split('_')[1].Length - fs.Extension.Length)));
```

Answer (score 5):

Ian Griffiths has a [natural sort for C#](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting). It makes no assumptions about where the numbers appear, and even correctly sorts filenames with multiple numeric components, such as app-1.0.2, app-1.0.11.

Comment: Good resource but don't we prefer to include code and not just a link, even one with an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

First you can extract the number:

```
static int ExtractNumber(string text)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(text, @"_(\d+)\.(png)");
    if (match == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int value;
    if (!int.TryParse(match.Value, out value))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Then you could sort your list using:

```
list.Sort((x, y) => ExtractNumber(x).CompareTo(ExtractNumber(y)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.png").OrderBy(n => n);
```

**EDIT**: As Marcelo [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833704/how-to-get-the-files-in-numeric-order-from-the-specified-directory-in-c#comment24271212_16833750), I belive you can get get all file names you can get their numerical part with a regex, than you can sort them including their file names.

Comment: The OP wants to sort _numerically_. I.e., page_2.png should come before page_11.png.

Answer (score 0):

This code would do that:

```
var dir = @"C:\Pictures";
var sorted = (from fn in Directory.GetFiles(dir)
                let m = Regex.Match(fn, @"(?<order>\d+)")
                where m.Success
                let n = int.Parse(m.Groups["order"].Value)
                orderby n
                select fn).ToList();

foreach (var fn in sorted) Console.WriteLine(fn);
```

It also filters out those files that has not a number in their names.

You may want to change the regex pattern to match more specific name structures for file names.